# Ruby 3.0.0 throwing NameError (uninitialized constant Boolean)

Tags: ruby

Literally, this is showing up in `irb` and in my application code. Suddenly ruby 3.0.0 is no longer recognizing Boolean

This worked a few weeks ago, it must have appeared after an OS update

```
$ irb
3.0.0 :001 > String
 => String 
3.0.0 :002 > Boolean
Traceback (most recent call last):
        4: from /Users/aronlilland/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/bin/irb:23:in `<main>'
        3: from /Users/aronlilland/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/bin/irb:23:in `load'
        2: from /Users/aronlilland/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/irb-1.3.0/exe/irb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        1: from (irb):2:in `<main>'
NameError (uninitialized constant Boolean)
```

#### env

- ruby 3.0.0p0 (2020-12-25 revision 95aff21468) [x86_64-darwin21]
- rvm 1.29.12 (latest) by Michal Papis, Piotr Kuczynski, Wayne E. Seguin [https://rvm.io]
- MacOS 12.5.1 (2.4 GHz 8-Core Intel Core i9 processor)

---

#### Troubleshooting steps already taken:

- uninstalled and reinstalled using RVM `rvm uninstall 3.0.0` then `rvm install 3.0.0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Ruby has never had a `Boolean` type](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/what-is-a-boolean). The Boolean constants `true` and `false` are, respectively, of types `TrueClass` and `FalseClass`, and both inherit directly from `Object`. There is not, and has never been, a type called `Boolean` in core Ruby.

Comment: ok good to know, but what does ActiveRecord or Mongoid (mongodb) use to resolve it then when models are being declared using type: Boolean? I've been using the keyword for 5 years now and all of a sudden its causing an error

Comment: I'm not as familiar with that side of Ruby, but a quick glance at the docs seems to indicate that `ActiveRecord` defines a constant called [`Boolean`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Type/Boolean.html) that it probably uses in models. If you were relying on that, it's possible the gem either got uninstalled or isn't being imported correctly now.

Comment: @alilland [tag:ruby] is not [tag:ruby-on-rails] and `irb` is not `rails c`. The Rails console does start IRB after loading a lot of dependencies ([See Here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/tools/console)). So you can't just run `irb` and expect to use all the black magic that the Rails ecosystem provides.